# Set-AWSSamlRoleProfile fails with "Unable to set credentials: "choices" should have at least one element." error

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, saml, federated-identity, aws-toolkit

I am trying to get a federated user access to AWS API using PowerShell. (Link provided below)

**AWS is properly configured to work with AD. (It works for bunch of my colleagues)**

I am using [PowerShell script](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-federated-api-access-to-aws-by-using-windows-powershell/) to access the AWS API's.

The problem occurs when I try to run the command `Set-AWSSamlRoleProfile`.

**Error:**

```
C:\Windows\system32> Set-AWSSamlRoleProfile -EndpointName $EndpointName -PrincipalARN $PrincipalARN -RoleARN $RoleARN -StoreAs 'SAMLUser' > $null

Set-AWSSamlRoleProfile : Unable to set credentials: "choices" should have at least one element.

At line:1 char:1

+ Set-AWSSamlRoleProfile -EndpointName $EndpointName -PrincipalARN $Pri ...

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Amazon.PowerShe...leProfileCmdlet:SetSamlRoleProfileCmdlet) [Set-AWSSamlRoleProfile], ArgumentException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException,Amazon.PowerShell.Common.SetSamlRoleProfileCmdlet
```

Any help or guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the issue was that the user (me) was not part of the group by AD.

Hope it helps someone else.